# Form not submitting Option Input value on POST

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, post

Got a simple form made of a text input and a option select input. When submititing, Firebug shows me that on POST no value from the option input has been sent, only the value from the text one. After checking other similar questions, don't find any spelling mistake...

FORM:

```
<form id="turn_conf" method="POST" action="config/forms/turn_conf/turn_insert.php">
    <div class="smartFormContent">
        <p class="inputForm">
            <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
            <input id="tu_name" class="" type="text" value="" name="tu_name">
        </p>
        <p class="inputForm">
            <label for="tipo">Tipo turno:</label>
            <select id="tu_type" class="" name="tu_type">
                 <option value="1">Mañana</option>
                 <option value="2">Tarde</option>
                 <option value="3">Noche</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <input class="smartFormSubmit" type="submit" value="Crear" name="submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

Firebug shows posted data as:

[image: Only text input is sent]

FIY: this POST form is sent by jQuery, here is the code:

```
function validaDatos(e) 
{
    var turnName = $('input[name=tu_name]').val();
    var turnType = $('input[name=tu_type]').val();

    $.post($(this).attr('action'), { tu_name:turnName, tu_type:turnType }).success(feedback);
    var emptyRow='<div class="tableRow newRow"><div class="contentColumn60"><span class="tableContentText"></span></div><div class="contentColumn20"><span class="tableContentText"></span></div><div class="contentColumn10"><div class="tableIconLink"></div></div><div class="contentColumn10"><div class="tableIconLink"></div></div></div>';
    $(emptyRow).prependTo('.tableContent').hide().slideDown(500);
messageInsert();
e.preventDefault(); 
}

function feedback (datos) {
    var content= datos;
    $('.newRow').html(datos);
}
```

Comment: post the jQuery method ;)

Comment: @CarlMarkham jQuery's functions were added on the question. Thank you.

Comment: tu_type is not an input, is a select

Comment: Thank you @ArnauOrriols, I am about to try as 'select[name=...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var turnType = $('input[name=tu_type]').val()
```

tu_type is not an input, is a select. This will work:

```
var turnType = $('select[name=tu_type]').val()
```

Comment: This was it. Gracias Arnau.

Answer (score 2):

There are duplicate FORM tags:

```
<form method="POST" action="config/forms/turn_conf/turn_insert.php" id="turn_conf">

<form id="turn_conf" method="POST" action="config/forms/turn_conf/turn_insert.php">
```

This will probably cause the browser not to post the data properly.

The two FORM tags also share the same ID which is not permitted `id="turn_conf"`.

Comment: This looks like a mistake in the question, not likely in the real code.

Comment: @jtherman excuse me, that was a mistake on copy/paste, sincerely I do not know why has that appeared as there is a single FORM opening tag. Xcuse for this. Thank you for your attention.